# Restrict "open" ethernet traffic to OpenVPN Traffic only when on a certain network

Tags: firewall, openvpn, pf, ipfw

I would like to set up a `pf` or `ipfw` firewall rule on my Mac OS X 10.8 notebooks so that all Traffic on wireless and cabled networks is restricted to calling "home" through OpenVPN when I'm not in the office.

In other (simpler/more mine) words:

As long as not on the `192.168.68.*` network with either my wireless or wired connection, disallow all traffic except OpenVPN connections.

Allow all traffic through the OpenVPN interface once it is set up.

Allow all traffic once directly connected to the `192.168.68.*` network with either the wireless or wired connection.

Thank you for any input on this, I hope there is an automatic/programmatic way of doing this...